# Проверка капчи в форме обратной связи

Tags: php

Есть отдельно проверка формы обратной связи и проверка капчи. Как вставить проверку капчи в код проверки формы? Вот код проверки формы обратной связи

```
`<?
  //Если форма отправлена
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 //Проверка Поля ИМЯ
  if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
  $hasError = true;
  } else {
  $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
  }
 //Проверка правильности ввода EMAIL
  if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
  $hasError = true;
  } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
  $hasError = true;
  } else {
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  }
 //Проверка наличия ТЕКСТА сообщения
  if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
  $hasError = true;
  } else {
  if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
  $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
  } else {
  $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
  }
  }
   //Если ошибок нет, отправить email
  if(!isset($hasError))  {
  $emailTo = 'darlex.box@hotmail.com'; //Сюда введите Ваш email
  $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
  $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
 mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
  $emailSent = true;
  }
  }
  ?>`
```

А вот код проверки капчи

```
`<?php
session_start();
if (md5($_POST['norobot']) == $_SESSION['randomnr2'])   { 
echo "Отлично , кажется, что вы не робот";
}
else {  
            echo "вы весьма надоедливый бот!";
    }
?>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После 
`if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Вставь

```
if (md5($_POST['norobot']) <> $_SESSION['randomnr2'])   { 
    $hasError = true;
}
```

Сессию стартуй где-то в index-е.